# Could not find i18n-0.7.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound) Openshift

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openshift, paas

I've been trying to push my RoR application to OpenShift, following the [railsgirls](http://guides.railsgirls.com/openshift/) tutorial, I come across this error while testing in development mode. Could not find i18n-0.7.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound) . I know this has been asked before, but the solutions on those questions don't fix the error.

Full Error Trace:

```
Could not find i18n-0.7.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
/var/lib/openshift/55f0f7b70c1e663a9e00019f/.gem/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize'
/var/lib/openshift/55f0f7b70c1e663a9e00019f/.gem/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
/var/lib/openshift/55f0f7b70c1e663a9e00019f/.gem/gems/bundler-1.10.6    /lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
/var/lib/openshift/55f0f7b70c1e663a9e00019f/.gem/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:140:in `specs'
/var/lib/openshift/55f0f7b70c1e663a9e00019f/.gem/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:185:in `specs_for'
/var/lib/openshift/55f0f7b70c1e663a9e00019f/.gem/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:174:in `requested_specs'
/var/lib/openshift/55f0f7b70c1e663a9e00019f/.gem/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
/var/lib/openshift/55f0f7b70c1e663a9e00019f/.gem/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
/var/lib/openshift/55f0f7b70c1e663a9e00019f/.gem/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:127:in `setup'
/var/lib/openshift/55f0f7b70c1e663a9e00019f/.gem/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.18/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:212:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.18/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb:69:in `load_app'
/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.18/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb:96:in `<module:App>'
/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.18/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb:4:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.18/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb:3:in `<main>'
```